# How to create a new attribute and put it in the product creation form as custom field?

Tags: product, custom-options

How to create a new attribute and put it in the product creation form as custom field?

It may be that I am calling it wrong, may be it's not an attribute but a product feature or characteristic.

The idea is to have an additional field, like the log description or the short description.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try this ? https://blog.amasty.com/beginners-guide-on-magento-product-attribute-sets/

Comment: This does not do what I need. I need it to be on the product creation form or "catalog_product/new" under the "General" tag. Thanks!

Comment: You need to create a new attribute first.  Maybe this is a better tutorial.
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html

Comment: I've seen this tutorial, but thanks! That's not what I need. I need an additionnal text area as the product log or short description, at the same place these descriptions.